# How to get value from tuple except known one?

Tags: python, tuples

Suppose we have a tuple with two elements:

```
a = (1, N)
```

or

```
a = (N, 1)
```

I know that one of the elements is 1, the position is unknown and I need to get value of second element other than 1.

Is there a way in Python to get it without iterating the tuple?

Comment: “Without iterating” would mean some `if..else` statement. But an iterative solution is probably shorter: `next(i for i in a if i != 1)`!?

Comment: Could both values in the tuple be 1? In that case this would return nothing

Comment: Why not iterate?

Comment: "Why not iterate?" - just wondering is there any elegant way to do it?

Comment: "Could both values in the tuple be 1?" - no, they are different

Comment: This is iterating, but may be considered "elegant" (at least it's short): `sum(a) - 1`

Comment: It wont works if element types aren't numeric.

Answer (score 3):

The built-in values of True and False, when used in the context of an integer, equate to 1 and 0 respectively. Therefore with no explicit if/else:

```
N = 99

a = 1, N
b = N, 1

print(a[a[0]==1])
print(b[b[0]==1])
```

**Output:**

```
99
99
```

Comment: Clever, but please don't ever use that in code that is meant to be comprehensible later on…

Comment: @deceze I will send all of my code to you for review

Answer (score 1):

Try use an if/else statement

```
if a[0] == 1:
   N = a[1]
else:
   N = a[0]
```

Or, to shorten this to one line, you could use the ternary operator:

```
N = a[0] if a[1] == 1 else a[1]
```

Comment: why are you assigning value to `N`?

Comment: For clarity. The question asked how to get the other element, which they represented as "N"

Answer (score 0):

You can go with `if/else`

```
a = (1, N)  #or a = (N, 1)

print(a[0] if a[0]!=1 else a[1])

#output
N
```